# Double linking to an additional library in a solution consisting of many projects?

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2019

I am new to c++ (switching from python). I have two projects in my solution (Visual Studio 2019):

1. a static library (let's call it "myLib") which has a dependency to a boost library.
2. an application (let's call it "myApp") which references myLib.

When i build myLib everything goes well. However, when I try to build myApp I get the following error:

> Blockquote Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib'  app C:\Users\[myName]\Documents\git_projects\[projectName]\app\LINK   1

I know it is about linker which cannot find the reference to the boost library, so when I link the boost library again from myApp, it builds without errors. 
Nevertheless, my question is:
**why do I have to reference boost twice? 1. in myLib I need to reference boost; 2. in myApp I also have to link to boost although myApp already references myLib.**
I thought that if I reference to boost in myLib, and then I reference to myLib from myApp, it would be possible to build everything without errors.
Could anyone explain to me if it is possible that myApp references only myLib without linking to boost?

Comment: Are you including date_time headers in your `myApp`? If so, then this is expected.

Comment: No, I do not. Instead, I include: asio, bind, foreach, property_tree, shared_ptr headers

Comment: You have me curious. I created a test and in fact, the top most project is looking for the boost library. Yet I know it is statically linked, my boost libs(dlls), are not in in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a library other libraries are not linked in. This is by design, you have to use special tools if you want to link a lib to another lib. Remove the dependency for the boost lib when you build your lib and it will still compile fine. With a lib as the taget and no boost lib dependencies.

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
void test_call() {
    boost::gregorian::date the_date;
}
```

Then the app. And even if the date_time lib is provided, the header is not:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\cpp\\boost_1_70_0\\stage\\lib\\libboost_date_time-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_70.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\cpp\\ConsoleTest\\Debug\\testing.lib")

void test_call();

int main(){
    test_call();
}
```

The reasoning is that if libs where included in other libs there would be a lot of code bloat. This prevents unnecessary code duplication.